# DataGridView VB.Net export to Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

**I have this Code to Export DataGridView to Excel and work very good, But how can i adapt it to Export only Visible Column not ALL Column what is in DGW.
I Show All my Code to use this Functions i just call  ExportExcel(dgwName) and work.

**

```
Sub ExportExcel(ByVal st As Object)
    Dim rowsTotal, colsTotal As Short
    Dim I, j, iC As Short
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Try
        Dim excelBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(excelBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlApp.Visible = True

        rowsTotal = st.RowCount
        colsTotal = st.Columns.Count - 1
        With excelWorksheet
            .Cells.Select()
            .Cells.Delete()
            For iC = 0 To colsTotal
                .Cells(1, iC + 1).Value = st.Columns(iC).HeaderText
            Next
            For I = 0 To rowsTotal - 1
                For j = 0 To colsTotal
                    .Cells(I + 2, j + 1).value = st.Rows(I).Cells(j).Value
                Next j
            Next I
            .Rows("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Rows("1:1").Font.Size = 12

            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
            .Cells.Select()
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
            .Cells(1, 1).Select()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        'RELEASE ALLOACTED RESOURCES
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
        xlApp = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question basically boils down to "how can I determine whether a column in a `DataGridView` is visible" and that is not something you need to ask us.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a condition that evaluates the `DataGridViewColumn.Visible` Property.